# Raise event from Inner class to outer class in c#

Tags: c#, events, inner-classes

I'm using MVVM pattern in my project.

My class design is like this:

```
Class Model : AbstractModel
{
   InnerClass Iclass = new InnerClass();

  Public String ModelProp1
  {
    get
    {
     return Iclass.prop1;
     }
    set
    {
      Iclass.prop1 = value;
    }
   }

public override void SetLabel(UInt16 value, int Index)
    {
        byte[] arr = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
        this.Iclass.IclassConfig[Index].Label = arr[0];
    }

 public override string DateFormat
    {
        get { return Iclass.intlDate.ToString(); }
        set { Iclass.intlDate = Convert.ToByte(value); }
    }
```

}

```
 Class InnerClass
{
public byte intlDate
 {
   get { return this.intl_date; }
        set { this.intl_date = value;
        RaiseModelPropertiesChangedEvent(new ValueChangedEventArgs {     Parameter_dateformat = this.intlDate });
  }

 private JClassa  []channel_config = new JClass[2];
 public JClass[] IclassConfig
    {
        get { return this.channel_config; }
        set { this.channel_config = value; }
    }
```

}

```
Public JClass
{
 private byte  channel_label;
  public byte Label
 {
  get { return this.channel_label; }
    set { this.channel_label = value;}
 }
```

I'm getting data from other application. updated data is coming in InnerClass property from there I want to push this updated data to Model class.

Problem is coming for JClass property how can I fire event such that It will push updated data to model class.

For this I have created Event in InnerClass like this:

```
 public event EventHandler<ValueChangedEventArgs> ModelPropertiesChanged;
  public void RaiseModelPropertiesChangedEvent(ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ModelPropertiesChanged != null)
            ModelPropertiesChanged(this, e);
    }
   public class ValueChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
   { 
      public int Parameter_dateformat { get; set; }
       public int Parameter_channelLabel { get; set; }
    }
```

Tell me how Can I achieve this. Becuase I have 4 property in Jclass and 6 Property is InnerClass.

Answer (score 0):

I would add event triggers in the setter of your inner class properties. Then in the Constructor of your parent class, move the IClass = new InnerClass() into your constructor and attach your event listeners.

Since you're MVVM you could leverage INotifyPropertyChanged, but heat will get messy in the long run.

Better to have a 'PropertyName'Changed event for each property you want to notify to the parent class.

Comment: but how Model class get JClass updated property value.

Comment: Do the same in JClass, when it's property value changes trigger an event that tells the parent class a new value is there. Most event signatures include the object as sender so you can inspect it directly from there. Since you have JClass collection, in the setter you will have to iterate each element to add your event handler.